# Flask-Session cleanup of expired sessions

Tags: python, session, flask

I am using flask-session for session handling. However I have a doubt on how expired sessions should be cleaned.
According to https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/17qou0/ask_flask_how_to_do_server_side_cleanup_on/
it is not done automatically.

Thus, I wrote a function that can be triggered periodically:

```
def delete_expired_sessions():
    '''
    This function gets all expired sessions from the DB and deletes them
    :return:
    '''
    session_interface=application.session_interface
        expired_sessions=session_interface.sql_session_model.query.filter(session_interface.sql_session_model.expiry <= datetime.utcnow())
    for es in expired_sessions:
        session_interface.db.session.delete(es)
        session_interface.db.session.commit()
```

Is this the correct way to do it or are there better ways?

Many thanks.
Michael

Comment: Note that the question you linked does not speak about flask-session, but only about flask itself. flask (not flask-session) sessions are based on cookies, so if you save any information based on the session in a database you need to clean it up sometimes. flask-session on the other hand is based on session in a database itself, so it seams reasonable that it supports cleaning up somehow.

Comment: I see. Anyway, it appears that at least for the Server side Flask-KVSession you need to trigger it manually (but it provides a function for deleting them) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027059/how-do-i-manage-cleaning-up-expired-sessions-using-flask-kvsession?rq=1

Comment: I haven't found anything similar for Flask-Session

Comment: You can read the sourcecode of Flask-Session, it's only 500 lines. It looks like when Redis, memcached or werkzeug.contrib.cache.FileSystemCache is used as backend sessions expire and get deleted via a backend dependent mechanism (e.g. in redis you can define how long something should be saved). When mongo or sqlalchemy is used as a backend, sessions are deleted when they are queried and they are expired. But I'm not sure, you should probably just look for yourself.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. It's true, there is not much code, but I wasn't sure if there wasn't anything else that could be used to take care of this and spent some time looking for an answer before doing it myself. So now there is a answer for future Flask-Session users.

Comment: BTW, to do a scheduled deletion I used what was suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027059/how-do-i-manage-cleaning-up-expired-sessions-using-flask-kvsession?rq=1

Comment: What backend do you use?

Comment: I am using SQLAlchemy